# Rearranging determinant products help

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Im trying to solve $Det(S^{-1}AS)$ given that $S$ is invertable. I do know the answer, which is only the determinant of $A$. However, I don't really understand why you can rearrange the determinant product in the following way. Would someone like to explain to me?

$$Det(S^{-1}AS)=Det(S^{-1})Det(A)Det(S) = Det(S^{-1})Det(S)Det(A) = \frac{1}{Det(S)}Det(S)Det(A)$$.

This step does not make sense to me: $Det(S^{-1})Det(A)Det(S) = Det(S^{-1})Det(S)Det(A)$

Would someone like to explain why we are allowed to do this?

Comment: What type of object is determinant of a  matrix?

Comment: it's because you are multiplying real numbers, same reason as why we are allowed to do $3\times 5\times 7 = 3\times 7\times 5$ for example

Comment: determinant of a square matrix is **a number**

Comment: Oh, ofcourse... Thanks! In my head I was still dealing with the actual determinant